# Motorcycle forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life

I’m trying to draw all of the forces acting on a motorcycle on an incline and I’ve provided a picture below. From research I’ve gathered that the drive force (S) need only be applied on the rear wheel of the motorcycle and this is a static friction force. Also rolling friction acts on both the front and rear tire and the rolling friction coefficient is distributed evenly on both tires. Is my research correct. Does my force body diagram portray all the forces correctly? Am i missing anything?

Comment: Your diagram is not posted.

Comment: No diagram yet ?